# HAVING clause to filter out null rows ONY if aggregate grouping contains not null values

Tags: sql-server, group-by, having

I'm trying to create an aggregate report from a table with schema

`PersonName varchar, IDNum int, CreateDate date`

PersonName and CreateDate are not null, however, IDNum is nullable, and there is no unique constraints on this table so that the same PersonName can have multiple`IDNums and even multiple null IDNums.

What I'm trying to do is create a report that groups by the CreateDate that ignores null IDNums if there exist ANY not null values for that date

So, if on February 1, a person exists with both IDNum 20,21,23,NULL,NULL the report aggregates 20, 21, 23 on the same date and ignores the nulls, if another person on February 1 exists with just NULL IDNum, they show up just once as NULL. If that person also exists on February 2 as IDNums 25, 30, NULL, they show up once in February 1 as NULL and again in February 2 as 25, 30 only. The null can be replaced with some other default value. It's not important.

So far I've got

`SELECT PersonName, COALESCE(IDNum, 0) IDNum, CreateDate FROM tbl
GROUP BY PersonName, COALESCE(IDNum, 0), CreateDate
HAVING COALESCE(IDNum, 0) >= CASE MAX(COALESCE(IDNum, 0)) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`

The idea here being if the IDNum evaluates to 0, don't evaluate it in the grouping if another IDNum evaluates to greater than 0 but this doesn't appear to be working. The results are identical as if the having clause just wasn't there and I can visually see several results of the same PersonName that contain both IDNums that are 0 and nonzero on the same date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this query. Just remove duplicating null values. Then count `IDNum`. Depending on that show your desired result

```
declare @t table (
    PersonName varchar(10)
    , IDNum int
    , CreateDate date
)

insert into @t
values
    ('A', 20, '20180216')
    ,('A', 21, '20180216')
    ,('A', null, '20180216')
    ,('A', null, '20180216')
    ,('B', null, '20180216')
    ,('C', null, '20180216')
    ,('C', null, '20180216')

select
    PersonName, IDNum, CreateDate
from (
    select
        *, cnt = count(*) over (partition by PersonName, CreateDate) 
    from
        @t
    group by PersonName, IDNum, CreateDate
) t
where
    cnt = 1
    or (cnt > 1 and IDNum is not null)
```

Output

```
PersonName, IDNum, CreateDate
-----------------------------
A           20     2018-02-16
A           21     2018-02-16
B           NULL   2018-02-16
C           NULL   2018-02-16
```

Comment: This is a good answer, the result set I have to work with is fairly large so it's not an ideal solution but it works and I think I can use it.